# how to detect ,on load of the html document, whether the body of the iframe document is ready to be displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose a HTML document has a iframe.
Using javascript,I want to detect ,on load of the html document,  whether the body of the iframe document is ready to be displayed.

I want to be able to overwrite the body contents (before it actullay loads) of the iframe.
Any suggestions? can I do it with jquery?

say if ,HTML doc is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="ifrmId"  src="http://www.google.com" >
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the onload event on the iframe element:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('ifrmId');
iframe.onload = function () {
  // iframe loaded
  var innerDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
};
```

**Edit:** With jQuery, exactly the same idea:

```
$('#ifrmId').load(function () {
  // iframe loaded
  var innerDocument = $(this).contents();
});
```

Keep in mind that if you want to manipulate the iframe's inner document, the file needs to be on the same domain, this is because the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions.